# Can a sitemap index file point to sitemaps in another directory?

Tags: seo, sitemap, xml-sitemap

I am creating multiple sitemaps for a site, and for the sake of organization I would like to put these sitemaps into their own directory (of course the sitemap.xml file will be in the root site directory).  Is this possible? I've looked through the protocol and it doesn't address this issue.

---

**UPDATE**

I did not clearly state my issue, which is this. If I have a sitemap index, can the sitemaps listed in the index be located in a subdirectory, such as `http://www.example.com/sub1/sub2/sitemap2.xml`? Sitemap2.xml does not include paths that is only for /sub2/. Sitemap2.xml might contains links such as `http://www.example.com/FooBar`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It used to be required to have your XML sitemaps in your root directory but it has since been changed to allow you to place your sitemaps within subdirectories of your choosing.

From http://www.sitemaps.org/faq.html#faq_sitemap_location

> **Q: Where do I place my Sitemap?**
>
> It is strongly recommended that you
>   place your Sitemap at the root directory of your HTML server; that is,
>   place it at `http://example.com/sitemap.xml`. In some situations, you
>   may want to produce different Sitemaps for different paths on your
>   site — e.g., if security permissions in your organization
>   compartmentalize write access to different directories. We assume that
>   if you have the permission to upload
>   `http://example.com/path/sitemap.xml`, you also have permission to
>   report metadata under `http://example.com/path/`. All URLs listed in the
>   Sitemap must reside on the same host as the Sitemap. For instance, if
>   the Sitemap is located at `http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml`, it can't
>   include URLs from `http://subdomain.example.com`. If the Sitemap is
>   located at `http://www.example.com/myfolder/sitemap.xml`, it can't
>   include URLs from `http://www.example.com`.

Comment: I wonder if multiple subdirectors are also OK, such as http://www.example.com/sub1/sub2/sub3/sitemap1.xml

Comment: Was it really ever required to have sitemaps in the root? I had mine in subdirectories years ago, right when XML sitemaps first came about.

Comment: And yes @RHPT the sitemap location can be wherever you wish at all.

Comment: _If the Sitemap is located at http://www.example.com/myfolder/sitemap.xml, it can't include URLs from http://www.example.com._ Note that the sitemap is for the items in the folder and folders below its location. In root, whole site. In Subdir, that subdir and below.

Comment: @FiascoLabs I meant "if the included sitemap in the sitemap index (located at the root) can be placed in a subdirectory". So example.com/sitemap.xml includes a sitemap at example.com/sub/sub/sitemap2.xml.